# Include JavaScript and HTML files in class diagram?

Tags: javascript, java, uml, class-diagram

My current application uses a JavaFX Application class with gui code (including a webview) and regular Java classes. This webview shows a html file which has JavaScript files as reference. My JavaScript has access to one of my classes like so:

```
private JSONModel model = new JSONModel();
JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
jsobj.setMember("java", model);
```

Meaning my d3.js has full access to call methods of my `JSONModel.class`. Since it is that important to the project, should I include it in my class diagram?  How would I make clear that it is JavaScript and not a Java class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not you include something in your class diagram depends on the purpose of this diagram.

If you think it's important to put it on there then I guess you should.

More or less the same applies for the difference between Java Class and JavaScript class; it all depends on the purpose and audience.

If the purpose of the diagram is to show the structure to a business analyst then you should not show the difference (it will only confuse the poor guy and will not help to get the message across).

If the purpose of the diagram is to instruct developers what to build, then you should somehow make the difference clear.
How you do this depends on your modeling method and tool. Some tools allow to set the language of the class.

From a pure UML standpoint I think you should work with something like a `Manifestation` to indicate that you implement a certain class in a certain artifact.

From UML 2.5 specs:
[image]

The manifestation relation can be between an artifact, and any `PackageableElement`

Comment: It actually is for other developers, precisly the documentation of the project.

Comment: @GeertBellekens can you elaborate the concept of "_manifest_" by providing an example?

Comment: @xmojmr I added an example from the UML specs.

Answer (score 2):

All important classes should be covered, especially when the required level of detail is low-level.

You can use `<<stereotype>>` to distinguish between `JavaScript` and `Java` classes as shown in [uml-diagrams.org: Submit Comments to Pluck, UML Sequence Diagram Example](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/pluck-comments-uml-sequence-diagram-example.html)

[[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLPw4.png)](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/pluck-comments-uml-sequence-diagram-example.html)

Comment: I don't think we should advocate the liberal use of stereotypes like that. Stereotypes are only valid if they are part of a profile that is being applied to the model. Simply starting to use stereotypes like this quickly leads to a big mess of all different stereotypes that are not defined in a meta model, and where nobody really knows what exactly they mean. I know because I'm still cleaning up a model with over 600! different stereotypes.

Comment: @GeertBellekens what would you recommend to distinguish between the `JavaScript` and `Java` side of the model. Namespaces? Packages?

Comment: You can use stereotypes, if that is the level of detail you are working on, but if you do then you should do it properly: Create a UML Profile that defines the different stereotypes and their properties (who become into tagged values in the model), not simple start using a new stereotype. Personally I try to avoid this level of detail as much as possible. It the fact that this class will be implemented in JavaScript really important? Maybe it doesn't really matter for the definition of the class, and maybe you could choose another technology as well without affecting the class's definition?

Comment: Or maybe that class will be implemented in Javascript, **and** in Pojo's **and** in the database... In that case it would be better to use the `Manifest` to indicate how a class is being implemented.